# Visualizing frequency of pixel change between several rasters using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have several rasters at my disposal. They come from a digitalization work according to a pre-established typology.
I would like to visualize the frequency of change of each pixel over time. Let me explain.

Let's say I have 3 rasters corresponding to 3 dates (same area; same resolution, same typology):

- If a pixel changes (of typology class) 3 times over time it obtains the value 3
- If a pixel changes (of typology class) 2 times over time it obtains the value 2
- If a pixel changes (typology class) 1 time over time it obtains the value 1
- If a pixel does not change the typology class over time, it obtains the value 0

Do you have an idea / solution to carry out this manipulation using ArcMap?

Comment: How many distinct values (typology classes) you have altogether? Also, how many different rasters you have for the same pixel?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I have like 20 typology classes noted by a code in the attribute table (for exemple, 420, 310, etc). In total I have 6 rasters of the same area, pixel size and coded with the same typology. The final objectif is to create a new raster exposing the frequence of typology code changes for each pixels. So like I said, for exemple, if a pixel change two times from one typology code to another It would have the value 2 in the resulting raster etc.

Comment: Try raster calculator (r1!=r2)+(r1!=r3)+(r2!=r3)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about consecutive changes or unique values?

if you are looking for unique values, use the Cell Statistics tool and choose variety as the statistics type. This tool is available with ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro if you have Spatial Analyst extension.

[image]

Getting consecutive changes a bit more challenging. 
You will create a subtracted raster for each consecutive time by using Raster Calculator

Raster2 - Raster1 = Difference1

Raster3 - Raster2 = Difference2 
.
.
.

Then, you will use Con tool

Difference1_bit = Con(Difference1, Difference1, 1 , "Value = 0")

Difference2_bit = Con(Difference2, Difference2, 1 , "Value = 0")
.
.
.

This will create rasters if there is no difference pixel value = 0 otherwise pixel value=1

You will use Raster Calculator one more time to add all Difference(n)_bit rasters to find the sum of changes for each pixel.

Difference1_bit
+
Difference2_bit
+
Difference3_bit

## ... =

Final_raster

Final raster will display how many times each pixel changed temporally

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try you methodology for unique values but it can be also nice to try to look for consecutive changes. Can you share it ?

Comment: I have extended my answer. I hope it helps. You can find other values such as majority, minority, mean, sum etc with Cell Statistics tool.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your methodology. I've tried and it works perfectly :)  (and sorry if my english was a bit bad, i'm French)